# How to get date from datepicker with bootstrap and show the date in another div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to get the date from a button and show it in another div.I have tried to use input tag method but it was not working.So I tried to use the button option with icon and my problem is how i can get the date and show it in another place.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-icon btn-primary w-full" id="date" data-plugin="datepicker">
<i class="icon wb-calendar" aria-hidden="true">
</i></button>
<div id="show-date"></div>
```

here is my js

```
$(function() {

  var showdate = document.getElementById( 'show-date' );
    $("#date").datepicker();
    $("#date").on("change",function(){
        var selected = $(this).val();
        showdate.selected.show;
     
    });
});
```

Comment: If you convert your showdate to jquery with `var showdate = $("#show-date")` then you can do `showdate.text(selected)`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen so how do i have to change the code here?Can u explain it please.

Comment: I've already gave you the code in the comment above, but you can see my answer there is also working example of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is multiple problems with your code, first a button can't trigger the change event, it has to be `changeDate`.

Second, to get the date your need to use `ev.date` since the buttons value will not be updated on the changeDate event.

```
$(function() {

  var showdate = $("#show-date")
  $("#date").datepicker().on('changeDate', function(ev) {
    var selected = ev.date
    showdate.text(selected)
  });
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$(function() {

  var showdate = $("#show-date")
  $("#date").datepicker().on('changeDate', function(ev) {
    var date = new Date(ev.date);
    var selected = ((date.getMonth() > 8) ? (date.getMonth() + 1) : ('0' + (date.getMonth() + 1))) + '/' + ((date.getDate() > 9) ? date.getDate() : ('0' + date.getDate())) + '/' + date.getFullYear()
    showdate.text(selected)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" integrity="sha512-mSYUmp1HYZDFaVKK//63EcZq4iFWFjxSL+Z3T/aCt4IO9Cejm03q3NKKYN6pFQzY0SBOr8h+eCIAZHPXcpZaNw==" crossorigin="anonymous"
  referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js" integrity="sha512-T/tUfKSV1bihCnd+MxKD0Hm1uBBroVYBOYSk1knyvQ9VyZJpc/ALb4P0r6ubwVPSGB2GvjeoMAJJImBG12TiaQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-icon btn-primary w-full" id="date" data-plugin="datepicker">
<i class="icon wb-calendar" aria-hidden="true">
</i></button>
<div id="show-date"></div>
```

Comment: @sleepy_coder Updated the demo, you can play around with the format.